# Writing maximum function

Tags: cplex, opl

I want to write a minimum function in OPL.

```
forall(p in P)
sum(n in N)Q6[n][p]==Min (Max_Rema*Dem[p],sum(m in M)Q4[m][n]) ;
```

I want that Q6 should be equal to minimum of `Max_Rema*Dem[p]` and `sum(m in M)Q4[m][n]`, where `Max_Rema` and `Dem[p]` are parameters. How to write this ?

Answer (score 0):

`minl` could help:

```
range P=1..3;
range N=1..4;

int Dem[p in 1..3]=p;
int Max_Rema=3;

dvar int Q4[N][P];
dvar int Q6[N][P];

subject to
{

forall(p in P) sum(n in N)Q6[n][p]==minl (Max_Rema*Dem[p],sum(m in N)Q4[m][p]) ;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it is returning 0. Here are the full details:

Q4 is calculated as:
  forall(m in M)
   sum(n in N)Q4[m][n]==P_Rem*sum(p in P)Q3[p][m]; // This is coming to be correct

Max_Rema=0.2; Dem[p] represents demand of p=6 customers, which is defined in .dat file; Dem=[600,500,300,900,1000,700];

forall(p in P)
 sum(n in N)Q6[n][p]==minl(Max_Rema*Dem[p], Q4[m][n]);

Where is the mistake ? I am not able to spot